# Can't use Jinja variable in jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

When I try to use a URL variable in jQuery.get, it doesn't work. But when I hardcode the contents, it works fine.

javascript:

```
1 - function readFile() {
2 -   var myurl = '{{ fName }}';         <<< jinja variable containing filename
3 -   console.log(myurl);                <<< prints correct URL in console
4 -   jQuery.get(myurl, function(data){
5 -    console.log(data);                <<< outputs a period (ie ".")
6 -    jQuery('#target').html(data);
7 -  });
8 - }
```

If I hardcode the output from line 3 into myurl in line 4, the function works and reads the file and displays its contents in the console.

I tried putting single quotes, double quotes, you name it around myurl in line 4 and nothing works.

@Mike

I'm calling the template from python as follows:

```
def hcheck():
    print("hckeck get")
    baseName = '/static/' + str(time.time())
    createDir(appDir + baseName)
    return render_template("hcheck_form.html", fName = baseName+'/healthCheck.txt')
```

The js code is in the hcheck_form.html. Is that what you meant?

*** UPDATE 1 ***
I compared the web.py Response Header (working) with the Flask Response Header, and I think that may be the root cause of my issue. Web.py returns the following:

```
Web.py
======
Request URL:         
https://<url>:8080/static/1565974246.91/healthCheck.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: <ip>:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 22
Content-type: text/plain
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 16:50:54 GMT
ETag: "1565974253.04"
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 16:50:53 GMT
Server: localhost
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Referer: https://<url>:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Flask
=====
Request URL: 
http://<url>:5000/static/1565974312.1353812/healthCheck.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: <ip>:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 16:51:58 GMT
ETag: "1565974317.914523-1-875239115"
Expires: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 04:51:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 16:51:57 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.4 Python/3.7.1
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Referer: http://<url>:5000/hcheck?radioId=hcheck
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36     
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Not being a web expert, I have a feeling it has something to do with Accept-Ranges: bytes, which isn't in the web.py header. Not sure. Is there a way to modify the Flask header to make it match what web.py returns? Thx

*** UPDATE 2 ***
Well this is embarrasing. Since I'm serving a static file, it is being cached and only shows original content, and not updated content as the function is updating it. If I manually clear the cache as the function is running, I can see the updates. No i just need to figure out how to turn off caching in Flask and I should be good to go. Thx

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Do you see the AJAX request being sent in the Network tab?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `console.log()` would log a different URL from the one that `jQuery.get` uses. I suspect there are some extra whitespace characters that you didn't notice in the log.

Comment: If we can't compare them, we can only guess they are different.

Comment: I wrapped the console.log output in brackets and don't see any spaces:

    [/static/1565823591.563554/healthCheck.txt]

That is output from the browser console. And that is what I hardcode in the url portion of the $.get() and it works.

Comment: But do you actually _serve_ the js file this code is in through jinja's renderer with the appropriate context variable `fName` set? Because if you don't, that template variable isn't a template variable: it's just the literal string `{{ fName }}`.

Comment: @Mike

I'm calling the template from python as follows:

    `def hcheck():
        print("hckeck get")
        baseName = '/static/' + str(time.time())
        createDir(appDir + baseName)
        return render_template("hcheck_form.html", fName = baseName+'/healthCheck.txt')`

The code is in the hcheck_form.html. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You still haven't said what you see in the Network tab. Is it sending the `GET` request? Is it being sent to the correct URL? Is a response being received?

Comment: Sorry...got sidetracked. Here is the content of the GET:

`Request URL: http://bla.bla.com:5000/static/1565824085.5153692/healthCheck.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: x.x.x.x:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 23:08:10 GMT
ETag: "1565824089.0187044-1-885397204"
Expires: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 11:08:10 GMT
Accept: */*
Referer: http://bla.bla.com:5000/hcheck?radioId=hcheck
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: @Barmar Please see updates above.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `Accept-ranges`, that just means that the Flask server is able to accept requests for partial data, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges

Comment: To disable caching, use `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`, and use the `cache: false` option. Or just add a cachebuster to the URL (that's what the option does).

Comment: @Barman That’s what I ended up doing thanks. Tried answering my own question yesterday but was barred by the system due to my noob’iness :).